# Why is this the value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
max( { 'a': 5, 'b': 6, 'c': 7, 'd': 4,})
```

gives `'d'`

Why isn't it giving `'c'`?

Answer (score 2):

The `max` function takes an iterable as a parameter, so when you pass a dict to it, the dict is iterated over as an iterable, rather than a mapping. And when used as an iterable, a dict simply returns an iterator over the keys of the dict, so given a dict `d`, `max(d)` really is equivalent to `max(d.keys())`, which is why `'d'` is returned in your example, as it has the highest value in lexicographical order among the keys of the dict.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!
diction1={ 'a': 5, 'b': 6, 'c': 7, 'd': 4,}
max(diction1.values())